# Azure Policy to Create/update diagnostic setting

Tags: azure-policy, azure-diagnostics

I am new to azure policy and i am trying to implement azure policy to enforce creation of diagnostic setting on azure resources.

My goal is to achieve below..

```
  - Create a diagnostic settings on resource every time a new resource is created. -- works
  - Recreate/modify if  diagnostics setting/destination  is manually changed or deleted. -- Not working 
  - Recreate/modify the diagnostics settings at scale when the assignment is recreated with different configuration. -- Not working
```

This is the policy i am using

```
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "anyof": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
                                "equals": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubAuthorizationRuleId",
                                "equals": "[parameters('eventHubAuthorizationRuleId')]"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubName",
                                "equals": "[parameters('eventHubName')]"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId",
                                "equals": "[parameters('workspaceId')]"
                            }
                        ]
```

My goal is to achieve below..

```
  - Create a diagnostic settings on resource every time a new resource is created. -- works
  - Recreate/modify if  diagnostics setting/destination  is manually changed or deleted. -- Not working 
  - Recreate/modify the diagnostics settings at scale when the assignment is recreated with different configuration. -- Not working
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure policy will enable diagnostic settings on newly created resources and will also modify the diagnostic settings if they have been updated or deleted manually.

```json
  {
 "mode": "All",
 "policyRule": {
   "if": {
     "field": "type",
     "equals": "*"
   },
   "then": {
     "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
     "details": {
       "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
       "name": "ensurediagnosticsettings",
       "existenceCondition": {
         "allOf": [
           {
             "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
             "notEquals": "false"
           },
           {
             "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubAuthorizationRuleId",
             "notEquals": ""
           },
           {
             "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubName",
             "notEquals": ""
           },
           {
             "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId",
             "equals": "[parameters('workspaceId')]"
           }
         ]
       },
       "deployment": {
         "properties": {
           "mode": "incremental",
           "template": {
             "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
             "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
             "parameters": {},
             "resources": [
               {
                 "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
                 "name": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '/', 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings')]",
                 "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                 "properties": {
                   "logs": [
                     {
                       "category": "default",
                       "enabled": true,
                       "retentionPolicy": {
                         "days": 365,
                         "enabled": true
                       }
                     }
                   ],
                   "metrics": []
                 }
               }
             ]
           },
           "parameters": {}
         }
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "parameters": {
   "workspaceId": {
     "type": "String",
     "metadata": {
       "displayName": "Workspace ID",
       "description": "The ID of the workspace for diagnostic settings."
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**Policy Assignment:**

[image]

The policy will make sure that all resources in the active subscription have their diagnostic settings enabled after it has been assigned to the scope.